# Razor View - Troubles with section

Tags: asp.net, razor, webmatrix

I just got some error that I don't expected to see...

To be clear, I'll show working code and code with error:

## This is working

_MainLayout.cshtml

```
<div id="content">
    <h1>@Page.Title</h1>
    @RenderSection("left", false)
    @RenderBody()
</div>
```

Page.cshtml

```
@section left{
<p>Some text on left side</p>
}

<div>
    Some content
</div>
```

In this case everything works fine, but when I deleted `@RenderSection("left", false)` inside the `_MainLayout.cshtml` I get the exception! Which case do I need it? See example below:

## This is not working

_MainLayout.cshtml

```
@if (WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated) {
    <h1>@Page.Title</h1>
    @RenderSection("left", false)
    @RenderBody()
} else {
    <h1>You not logged in!</h1>
    <p>To see this page, you have to login first.</p>
}
```

Page.cshtml

```
@section left{
<p>Some text on left side</p>
}

<div>
    Some content
</div>
```

In this case, if user is not authenticated, I have this exception:

**Description:** `An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.`

**Exception Details:** `System.Web.HttpException: Следующие разделы были определены, но не были обработаны для страницы макета "~/_MainLayout.cshtml": "left".`
**Which can be translated as:** `Section was created but wasn't rendered for layout page "~/_MainLayout.cshtml": "left".`

**Source Error:**

`An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.`

**Stack Trace:**

```
[HttpException (0x80004005): Следующие разделы были определены, но не были обработаны для страницы макета "~/_MainLayout.cshtml": "left".]
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.VerifyRenderedBodyOrSections() +91298
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext() +332
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +95
   System.Web.WebPages.<>c__DisplayClass7.<RenderPageCore>b__6(TextWriter writer) +102
   System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult.WriteTo(TextWriter writer) +12
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult result) +67
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.RenderSurrounding(String partialViewName, Action`1 body) +66
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext() +262
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +95
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpHandler.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpContext context) +249
```

The question is: how can I make it work?
Any advice is valuable!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're still declaring the section in your child view, and the razor rendering engine doesn't know what to do with it.

I'm not sure what the best way to deal with it would be some possible workarounds are:

- Move the `RenderSection("left", false)` outside of the body of the `if` block.
- Process your security in the controller, and display a different view altogether if the user shouldn't see anything (*this is probably preferable*)

Comment: Thats funny, but I'm not using MVC. (I'm just playing around with WebMatrix and trying to realize some of my idea) Thats why processing security on each page is kind of silly... But I'll try to make a redirection to error page. Maybe it'll work. Thank you fo pointing me in this ;)

Comment: Ah sure, I should have picked up on the WebSecurity class. I haven't got a lot of experience with WebMatrix, but I assume Razor behaves in a similar way. You might be trying to do something that's a little beyond WebMatrix?

Comment: Yes, I do. I figured out taht WebMatrix not fit me as match as I expected. But still it have some very usefull stuff. Now I'm using `Context.RedirectLocal` which is redirecting user to error page,  when he isn't logged in. This works fine for me.

Comment: I don't see how this could be beyond WebMatrix. Even though it's geared towards beginners, or atleast marketed as a simple product, it has the full power of the .NET Framework behind it.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this "issue" still persists with Razor (*WebPages actually*). A common solution I've seen (*and implemented when needed*) is to silently discard the section contents to a null `TextWriter`:

```
@if (WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated) {
    <h1>@Page.Title</h1>
    @RenderSection("left", false)
    @RenderBody()
} else {
    <h1>You not logged in!</h1>
    <p>To see this page, you have to login first.</p>
    @{
        WriteTo(TextWriter.Null, RenderSection("left"));
    }
}
```

The call to `RenderSection` satisfies the imposed requirement of calling a corresponding `RenderSection` for each section defined. Dumping to `TextWriter.Null` discards the contents, and ensures minimal impact on memory consumption (*other implementations have used `new StringWriter()`, but the content temporarily buffered in memory*)

It's a hack, but it works; I'm trying to hide it away as part of the rendering process.